# Как сгруппировать блоки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Привет, как с помощью js можно сгруппировать блоки с классом dar, чтобы под каждой датой они были в одном блоке?

```
          <div id="cont">
                <div class="val">2016-04-08</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 2</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 1</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-07</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-06</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 3</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 3</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 3</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-04</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 3</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-03</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 3</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-09</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="dar">3000 / 3</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-01</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-02</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 5</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-11</div>
                <div class="dar">1000 / 1</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-20</div>
                <div class="dar">3000 / 1</div>
                <div class="val">2016-04-15</div>
                <div class="dar">2000 / 3</div>
            </div>
```

если что он выполняется так

```
    Object.keys(arr).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
      //  console.log(arr[val].length)
        console.log(val)
        $('#cont').append('<div class="val">'+val+'</div>');
          arr[val].forEach(function(val, idx, array){
          $('#cont').append('<div class="dar">' + val.skuId + " / " + val.guantity + '</div>');
           console.log(val.skuId + " / " + val.guantity);
        });
    });
```

просто нужно будет делать аккардион из этих данных

Comment: Каким образом сгруппировать блоки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите и добавьте обертку, не выводя все разом в контейнер сразу же. Сначала соберите разметку в строку перед тем, как добавлять в контейнер, а потом уже примените `append`. Простой пример, для наглядности использующий [JQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = {
    "2016-01-08" : [
      { "skuId" : 1000, "guantity" : 1 }, 
      { "skuId" : 2000, "guantity" : 2 },
      { "skuId" : 3000, "guantity" : 3 } 
    ],
    "2016-02-08" : [
      { "skuId" : 1000, "guantity" : 1 },
      { "skuId" : 1000, "guantity" : 3 }
    ],
    "2016-03-08" : [
      { "skuId" : 1000, "guantity" : 1 }
    ],
    "2016-04-08" : [
      { "skuId" : 1000, "guantity" : 1 }
    ]
  };
  
  Object.keys(arr).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
      $('#cont').append('<div class="val">'+val+'</div>');
      
      var construct = '<div>';
      arr[val].forEach(function(val, idx, array){
          construct += '<div class="dar">' + val.skuId + " / " + val.guantity + '</div>';
      });
      construct += '</div>'
      
      $('#cont').append(construct);
  });
  
  $( "#cont" ).accordion();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: Большое, тебе человеческое спасибо!!!, а я голову ломал целый день